Google Autocomplete Text box for Razor Page
I'm developing a page where customers can fill in there address detail. I'm looking for way to autocomplete the address, based on what the user has type and select the correct address from the google suggestions.
I have already created the API key and can import maps etc. into my page, I just cannot het the autocomplete to work.
I'm using Blazor with razor pages and C#
Can anybody please help me with demo code or a link.
Thanks,
